# Hotkey in Pynput Controller

Tags: python, keypress, pynput

How to simulate a hotkey press using Pynput Controller for eg: `shift + s + down`
I want all the three keys in the eg to be pressed simultaneously

I want something like this:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.shift + 's' + Key.right)
time.sleep(0.1)            
keyboard.release(Key.shift + 's' + Key.right)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `Key` class [here](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#global-hotkeys), to a list of all the avaiable keys.

You can simulate pression with the function `.press()`:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
import threading

class MyClicker():
    def __init__(self, keys):
        self.keys = keys
        self.controller = Controller()

        self.start_press = False

    def Press(self, key):
        while not self.start_press:
            pass
        self.controller.press(key)

    def Run(self):
        #Create a thread for each key press
        for press_key in self.keys:
            threading.Thread(target=self.Press, args=(press_key,)).start()
        
        self.start_press = True
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.start_press = False

        for release_key in reversed(self.keys):
            self.controller.release(release_key)

MyClicker([Key.shift, 's', Key.down]).Run()
```

Comment: Actually, I don't want to detect keypresses. I want to simulate them virtually through pynput

Comment: @Saat answer updated, can you tell me if now is ok?